# Determine what is the level of chlid php

Tags: php, codeigniter, recursion, parent-child

I am trying to get parent child relation and successfully get that But I am stuck how to identify what is the level of the child.

Here is my code

```
   public function getDownline($userid = null) {
        $category_data = array();

        $where = array('parent_id' => $userid);
        $this->db->where($where);
        $category_query = $this->db->get('users')->result();

        $category_data = array();
        foreach ($category_query as $category) {
            $category_data[$category->id] = array($category);
            $children = $this->getDownline($category->id);
            if ($children) {
                $category_data[$category->id]['children'] = $children;
            }
        }

        return $category_data;
    }
```

Below is my table structure

[image]

I am getting output in this format

```
 [1136] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1136
                    [gid] => 4
                    [parent_id] => 1112
                    [username] => test
                    [email] => abc@abc.com
                    [name] => test
                    [status] => 1
                    [registerd] => 2017-04-20 08:49:25
                    [last_login] => 2017-04-21 10:42:25
                    [password] => 4eca045dfa240f56a1f9d45eaa53b71c6eccd6a7
                    [tranjection_password] => 
                )

            [children] => Array
                (
                    [1148] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 1148
                                    [gid] => 4
                                    [parent_id] => 1136
                                    [username] => test_downline
                                    [email] => kapil@abc.in
                                    [name] => test_downline
                                    [status] => 1
                                    [registerd] => 2017-04-21 10:42:56
                                    [last_login] => 2017-04-21 11:08:00
                                    [password] => 4eca045dfa240f56a1f9d45eaa53b71c6eccd6a7
                                    [tranjection_password] => 
                                )

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [1150] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1150
                                                    [gid] => 4
                                                    [parent_id] => 1148
                                                    [username] => test1_downline1
                                                    [email] => kapil25@abc.in
                                                    [name] => test1_downline1
                                                    [status] => 1
                                                    [registerd] => 2017-04-21 11:08:27
                                                    [last_login] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                                                    [password] => 4eca045dfa240f56a1f9d45eaa53b71c6eccd6a7
                                                    [tranjection_password] => 
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1149] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 1149
                                    [gid] => 4
                                    [parent_id] => 1136
                                    [username] => test_downline2
                                    [email] => kapil1@abc.in
                                    [name] => test_downline2
                                    [status] => 1
                                    [registerd] => 2017-04-21 11:06:35
                                    [last_login] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                                    [password] => 4eca045dfa240f56a1f9d45eaa53b71c6eccd6a7
                                    [tranjection_password] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should do this in an object context here
something like that should work

```
class Users_Model extends CI_Model
{

    public function getDownline(User_Object $obj, $level = 0) 
    {
        $obj->level = $level;

        $where = array('parent_id' => $obj->id);
        $this->db->where($where);
        $query = $this->db->get('users')->result("User_Object");

        foreach ($query as $objUser) 
        {
            $obj->add($objUser);
            $this->getDownline($objUser, ($level+1));
        }
        return $obj;
    }

    public function downline_income($userId = null, $offset = 0) 
    { 
        $userId = user::id(); 
        $objUser = new User_Object;
        $objUser->id = $userId;
        $downline = $this->user->getDownline($objUser);
    }
}


class User_Object
{
    private $children = [];
    public $level = 0;

    public function add(User_Object $obj)
    {
        $this->children[] = $obj;
    }

}
```

Comment: getting error : Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::add()

Comment: how do you call getDownline function from controller ? show me your code pls

Comment: `public function downline_income($userId = null, $offset = 0) {
        $userId = user::id();
          $downline = $this->user->getDownline($userId);`

Comment: naaa that won't work dude... do you even read my code ? ;)
I've posted an update

Comment: `Message: Argument 1 passed to user::getDownline() must be an instance of User_Object, boolean given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\maxflexonline\app\controllers\Account.php on line 505 and defined` now this is the error with updated code

Comment: you see the function downline_income in my answer... no offense, but you should be able to understand the code in order to use it ;)