# undefined index issue after casting from object to array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object, casting

I am facing a problem, few days ago I had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43538769/determine-what-is-the-level-of-chlid-php) issue which is solved but when I was retrieving data it was object so with the help of the below code I have converted that as array but now when I try to access the array I am getting `Undefined index` notice.

**Controller**

```
public function downline_income($userId = null, $offset = 0) {
        $userId = user::id();
        $limit = AZ::setting('record_per_page');
        $objUser = new User_Object;
        $objUser->id = $userId;
        $downline = $this->user->getDownline($objUser);
        $downline = $this->object_to_array($downline);
        AZ::layout('left-content', array(
            'block' => 'account/downline_income',
            'user' => $userId,
            'q' => $userId,
            'data' => $downline,
        ));

public function object_to_array($obj) {
    if (is_object($obj))
        $obj = (array) $obj;
    if (is_array($obj)) {
        $new = array();
        foreach ($obj as $key => $val) {
            $new[$key] = $this->object_to_array($val);
        }
    } else
        $new = $obj;
    return $new;
}
```

When `var_dump` in `downline_income.php`**(view)** below is the output.

```
//code
$as = $data;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($as['User_Objectchildren']);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
array(3) {
  ["User_Objectchildren"]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    array(22) {
      ["User_Objectchildren"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["level"]=>
      int(1)
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "1147"
      ["gid"]=>
      string(1) "4"
       //
       ...
```

And on `print_r`

```
Array
(
    [User_Objectchildren] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [User_Objectchildren] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [level] => 1
                    [id] => 1147
                    [gid] => 4
                    [parent_id] => 1112
                    [username] => test 9
                    [email] => kapil789654@abc.com
                    [name] => test9
                    [status] => 0
                    [registerd] => 2017-04-20 09:03:10
                    [last_login] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [password] => 4eca045dfa240f56a1f9d45eaa53b71c6eccd6a7
                    [tranjection_password] => 
                    [package_id] => 6
                    [user_id] => 1147
                    [purchase_date] => 2017-04-20 09:03:11
                    [confirm_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [package_name] => USD 1000
                    [amount] => 1000
                    [daily_income] => 12
                    [total_income] => 600
                    [time_duration] => 60
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [User_Objectchildren] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [level] => 1
                    [id] => 1146
                    [gid] => 4
                    [parent_id] => 1112
                    [username] => test8
.....
```

When try to print `print_r($as['User_Objectchildren']);`

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message:  Undefined index: User_Objectchildren
>
> Filename: account/downline_income.php
>
> Line Number: 43

Comment: Err, where is line 43?

Comment: `print_r($as['User_Objectchildren']);` is the code on #43

Comment: What is `$as`? In your question there is no connection between the line with the error and the code block you provided... If you could show *one* code block which both defines the variable *and* produces the error, we could say something more useful.

Comment: @trincot : check updated question.

Comment: You did not turn it into *one* code block. Now what is *$data*? Do you understand what I am saying?

Comment: And I notice, the `object_to_array` function is nested. Is it a typo or it is as it is?

Comment: @trincot : this code is in `CI` so data is the key, as you can see in first code block `'data' => $downline,`. And `object_to_array` function I found that by google to convert object to array recursively.

Comment: A `'data'` key is not the same thing as a `$data` variable. Is it really impossible to provide a reproducible piece of code? Anyway I'm moving on. Maybe someone else can help you.

Comment: @trincot : you can check the updated question

Comment: I won't: it still has an undefined `$data` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at both question and found that you can do that without creating objects. So you don't need to `cast` any object to array. You will get simple `std array`.

follow the below code.

**Controller**

```
public function downline_income($userId = null, $offset = 0) {
    $userId = user::id();
    $limit = AZ::setting('record_per_page');
    $objUser = new stdClass();
    $objUser->id = $userId;
    $downline = $this->user->getDownline($objUser);

    AZ::layout('left-content', array(
        'block' => 'account/downline_income',
        'user' => $userId,
        'total_users' => $total_users,
        'pagination' => $pagination,
        'q' => $userId,
        'data' => $downline,
        'offset' => $offset,
    ));
}

public function getDownline($obj, $level = 0) {
    $obj->level = $level;

    $where = array('parent_id' => $obj->id);
    $this->db->select('users.*');
    $this->db->where($where);

    $query = $this->db->get('users')->result();

    foreach ($query as $objUser) {
        $obj->data[] = $this->getDownline($objUser, ($level + 1));
    }

    return $obj;
}
```